# Write out multiple gtsummary objects to a single word file

Tags: r, dplyr, gtsummary

I would like to use the user function I created (that uses "tbl_cross"), to create a single word document with all my cross tables.

Here is the data:

```
  library(readr)
  library(magrittr)
  library(gtsummary)

dat <- read_table2('Q17_1   Q17_2   Q17_3   Q17_4   survey
No  Yes No  Yes m1
No  Yes No  No  m2
Yes Yes Yes Yes m1
No  No  Yes No  m2
No  No  Yes Yes m1
Yes No  Yes No  m2
No  No  Yes Yes m1
No  No  Yes No  m2
Yes No  Yes Yes m1
')
```

This is a function I created to generate a single table:

```
run_xtab <- function(v1) {
  out <- dat %>%
    tbl_cross(
      !!rlang::sym(v1),
      col = survey,
      percent = 'column',
      label = list(survey~v1),
      missing_text = "missing"
    ) %>%
    add_p(source_note = TRUE) %>%
    bold_labels()
  
  return(out)
}

run_xtab('Q17_1')
```

[image]

To write out one table I can use:

```
run_xtab('Q27_4') %>% 
  as_flex_table() %>% 
  flextable::save_as_docx(path = paste0(dir_project_foll,"Output",'test.docx'))
```

To generate multiple table I use:

```
lapply(c('Q17_1','Q17_2','Q17_3')),run_xtab)
```

How do I *write all* these tables into a *single word document*? Any suggestions appreciated!

I tried:

```
t <- lapply(c('Q17_1','Q17_2','Q17_3')),run_xtab) 
t %>%  as_flex_table() %>% flextable::save_as_docx(path = paste0(dir_project_foll,"Output",'test.docx'))
```

But it throws an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

Comment: If you create your tables in an R Markdown document instead of a script you can put all the tables in a single document. You don't need the save_as_docx() function for the Rmd file.

Comment: @Daniel D. Sjoberg Thanks for the suggestions, I am not too familar with Rmarkdown, but I will give it a try!

Comment: @Daniel D. Sjoberg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69125266/write-out-multiple-gtsummary-objects-to-a-single-word-file-using-rmarkdown

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can still rely on save_as_docx() function; check it out on
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/flextable/versions/0.7.0/topics/save_as_docx (check the first argument)

```
library(readr);
library(magrittr);
library(gtsummary);
library(tidyverse);
library(officer);
library(flextable);

run_xtab('Q17_1')
lapply(c('Q17_1','Q17_2','Q17_3'),run_xtab) 

Q17_1 <- run_xtab('Q17_1')
Q17_2 <- run_xtab('Q17_2')

tb1 <- as_flex_table(Q17_1, include =everything(), return_calls = FALSE, strip_md_bold =  FALSE)
tb2 <- as_flex_table(Q17_2, include =everything(), return_calls = FALSE, strip_md_bold =  FALSE)

sect_properties <- prop_section(
  page_size = page_size(orient = "portrait",
                    width = 8.3, height = 11.7),
 type = "continuous",
  page_margins = page_mar()
)

save_as_docx(tb1, tb2, values = NULL, path = "Table1_and_2.docx" , pr_section = sect_properties)
```

[This is example on how to export the first two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3BDj.png)